# Ruby On Rails uploading songs to Rackspace Cloud Files container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rackspace-cloud

Ok so here's the deal, I'm creating a web app and I'm adding the function to upload music to user profiles. I'm using Rackspace cloud files for storage, and I'm having a little bit of trouble completing two task. Firstly I'm having trouble writing the code to upload the file to my container. Secondly I need to generate the url of the file to store in the database. I'm very new to integrating API's so i don't have a lot of knowledge.

```
object = container.create_object 'filename', false
object.write file
```

Is this code correct for uploading the files?

Comment: [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) will handle both these tasks easily and natively supports rackspace cloud.  You should look into it.

Answer (score 0):

## Using fog directly

First of all, if you're not already using it, the officially supported Ruby library for interacting directly with Cloud Files from Ruby is [fog](http://fog.io/). To start, add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'fog'
```

Then run `bundle install` to install it.

To upload a file and get its public url, using fog directly:

```
# Use your Rackspace API key, not your password; you can find your API key by logging
# in to the control panel, clicking on your name in the top-right, and choosing
# "account settings".

service = Fog::Storage.new(
  provider: 'rackspace',
  rackspace_username: ENV['RACKSPACE_USERNAME'],
  rackspace_api_key: ENV['RACKSPACE_API_KEY']
)

dir = service.directories.create key: 'directory-name', public: true

files_to_upload.each do |path|
  file = dir.files.create key: File.basename(path), body: File.open(path, 'r')
  puts "public URL for #{file} is #{file.public_url}"
end
```

## Using CarrierWave

However! What you're doing is a pretty common usecase in Rails, so there's a gem for it: [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). Add the following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave'
```

And run `bundle install` to install it. Now configure CarrierWave to use Cloud Files:

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider           => 'rackspace',
    :rackspace_username => 'xxxxxx',
    :rackspace_api_key  => 'yyyyyy'
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'name_of_directory'
end
```

Next generate an *uploader*:

```
rails g uploader Song
```

Now you can use the `SongUploader` to store and retrieve Song data. See the generated code, or the [CarrierWave docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), for more details.